# Plotting points on a map with calculated distance

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, cartopy

This is my dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import Point
import geopandas as gpd
from geopandas import GeoDataFrame
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = {"STATE" : [ "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ"], 
     "CATEGORY": ["A", "B", "C", "D"],
     "LATITUDE" : [ 40.794856, 40.790176, 40.826762, 40.495150], 
     "LONGITUDE" : [ -74.149086, -74.255100, -74.101990, -74.442890]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df.plot(kind="scatter", x="LONGITUDE", y="LATITUDE", alpha=0.4)
plt.show()
```

[image]

I want to calculate the distance between points based on category column:

A -> B

A -> C

A -> D

and connect the dots with distance displayed between them as a label

```
#creating point object so I can calculate distance bwtween coordinates
df["point"] = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df['LONGITUDE'], df['LATITUDE'])]
#Formula I use for calculating distance between two points, this works when I have two seperate columns
#df['lat_long_diff'] = df.apply(lambda x : geodesic((x['LATITUDE_A'],x['LONGITUDE_A']),(x['LATITUDE_other_points'],x['LONGITUDE_other_points'])).miles,axis=1)
```

Also if I could include the Map of New Jersey as background it would be great, just the outline map would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import cartopy
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.text import Text

import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd

import geopy.distance


def calc_dist(point_a, point_b):
    return(geopy.distance.geodesic(point_a, point_b).miles)

def draw_lines(x, y, p1 , p2):
    x1, x2 = x[p1], x[p2]
    y1, y2 = y[p1], y[p2]
    ax.plot([x1,x2],[y1,y2])


d = {"STATE" : [ "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ"], 
     "CATEGORY": ["A", "B", "C", "D"],
     "LATITUDE" : [ 40.794856, 40.790176, 40.826762, 40.495150], 
     "LONGITUDE" : [ -74.149086, -74.255100, -74.101990, -74.442890]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

dist_list = []
for i in [1,2,3]:
    dist = calc_dist((df.at[0, 'LATITUDE'], df.at[0, 'LONGITUDE']),
                    (df.at[i, 'LATITUDE'], df.at[i, 'LONGITUDE']))
    dist_list.append(dist)

proj = ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=0)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection=proj), figsize=(16,16))
ax.set_extent([df['LONGITUDE'].min()-1,
               df['LONGITUDE'].max()+ 1,
               df['LATITUDE'].min()- 1,
               df['LATITUDE'].max()+1], 
              crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())

x = df['LONGITUDE'].tolist()
y = df['LATITUDE'].tolist()

ax.scatter(x, y)

draw_lines(x, y, 0, 1)
draw_lines(x, y, 0, 2)
draw_lines(x, y, 0, 3)

ax._add_text(Text(text=str(round(dist_list[0], 2)), x=-74.20, y=40.82))
ax._add_text(Text(text=str(round(dist_list[1], 2)), x=-74.12, y= 40.8))
ax._add_text(Text(text=str(round(dist_list[2], 2)), x=-74.29, y= 40.64))

ax.add_feature(cfeature.STATES.with_scale('10m'), zorder=0)

fig.canvas.draw()
fig.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: could you explain `ax._add_text()` and its parameters?

Comment: It's used to add the distance labels to the lines. The first parameter is the text that is stored in the dist_list and accessed via index. However the values are rounded and type cast to strings. The next 2 parameters are the x,y coords, or in this case, the longitude and latitude.

Comment: Do you mean for the label position coordinates? I just hardcoded those for this example to make it easy to get the labels in a position that made sense. For more complicated situations you might have some success with the from adjustText package. You could also do some sort of positioning off of the line midpoint coordinates.

Comment: @MurtazaHaji if this answers your question, please up vote and mark as accepted answer. If not, tell me what changes you need and I will make them.

Comment: I have been trying to get this to run over my dataframe coz i have varying lists of points. I am accepting this answer for now. Might look for update here or on a different question.